# Changing shell theme in without Gnome Tweak Tool

Tags: gnome, themes

How do I go about doing so? Gnome tweak tool won't launch under gnome 3 and I want to know if there is any other way of changing the shell theme. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean, it won't launch under GNOME 3?  Are you using the stock GNOME 3?  Are you on oneiric, precise, etc.?  On my oneiric system, it's as simple as typing "tweak" in the Applications search; the icon is actually titled "Advanced Settings".

Comment: Using 12.04. And yes, everytime I click on it, nothing happens.

Comment: I got this too, it seems to be a bug with gnome-tweak-tool, gnome-shell or the user theme extension. Whenever the extension is installed, gnome tweak tool can't start (it crashes immediately after starting). I hope this will get fixed soon.

Comment: Yeah, that's how it happened. Right after I installed the user theme extension.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [How to report a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Do sudo nautilus in your favorite Terminal emulator.
2. Navigate to usr/share/themes/
3. Drop in the theme folder (should be theme name, and have a folder inside called gnome-shell)
4. Rename folder default to oldefault
5. Rename new theme folder to default.
6. Open the run dialogue and type r
7. Done!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, but was able to easily uninstall the extension via the gnome shell extensions web page: https://extensions.gnome.org/local/